# Not able to install GitLab Kubernetes managed application prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, prometheus

Currently I'm facing the following issue when trying to deploy a Kubernetes application managed by GitLab.

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"]
68  Error: plugin "diff" exited with error
```

I've added a kubernetes cluster via certificate to my gitlab instance and activated the Prometheus toggle within integrations. As well the cluster management project is assigned and a gitlab-runner within the cluster.

The `helmfile.yaml` looks as following:

```
helmDefaults:
  atomic: true
  wait: true

  # ---------------------  IMPORTANT ---------------------------
  # Uncomment the paths below for the applications that you'd like to manage.
  # By default all the helmfiles have `install:true`. So if you uncomment one of these
  # helmfiles, the associated application will be tried to be installed or updated.
  #
  # You can set `install:false` to either uninstall the app from your cluster, or
  # keep it uninstalled if you don't have it already installed.
  #
  # For more information, reference the Helmfile repository at:
  # https://github.com/roboll/helmfile
  # ------------------------------------------------------------

helmfiles:

  # - path: applications/cilium/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/ingress/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/cert-manager/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/sentry/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/gitlab-runner/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/elastic-stack/helmfile.yaml
  - path: applications/prometheus/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/vault/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/fluentd/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/falco/helmfile.yaml
  # - path: applications/apparmor/helmfile.yaml
```

Any suggestions what I'm missing?

Comment: that's almost certainly a kubernetes version mismatch, since `v1beta1` was [removed in 1.22](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#rbac-resources-v122), but since you didn't see fit to include any relevant version info of **anything**, it's just a guess

Comment: So got your critic. Thanks. Did not no that's maybe related to a version mismatch so saw no need to include version information. Will provide more information asap.

Answer (score 0):

Posted community wiki for better visibility with general solution as there are no further details / logs provided. Feel free to expand it.

---

As @mdaniel suggests in the comments:

> that's almost certainly a kubernetes version mismatch, since v1beta1 was removed in 1.22, but since you didn't include any relevant version info of anything, it's just a guess

Please find more information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#webhook-resources-v122)